# Re-render view with component after destroy in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

So I have this issue where Ember will not render my view more than once, even after I have destroyed it.

The code I have, works without using components, so it is probably some issue with the actual view not being destroyed properly.

**I render into an outlet in my ApplicationRoute**

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    showModal: function() {

      // This does not work the second time:
      this.render('modal', {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });

    }
  }
});
```

**I set up an event listener for when the Bootstrap modal is hidden**

```
App.BaseModalComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$('.modal')
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){

          // I am destroying the component, 
          // when the modal is hidden
          self.destroy();

        })
        .modal();
  }
});
```

The `afterRenderEvent` is a listener I have attached to the view's `afterRender` event.

See here for markup, etc.: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wolicutiwiro/1/edit

A working example without using components: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lodamojikaqo/1/edit

Comment: why are you calling destroy?..why not disconnectOutlet from router? Any specific reason?

Comment: @CodeJack That's what worked in my view. I didn't know about the `disconnectOutlet` method before. I am closer to a solution after looking at Ghost source code. But I can't figure out how to call disconnectOutlet from my `hidden.bs.modal` event listener.

Comment: ok i will edit your jsbin about `disconnectOutlet`

Comment: just check if this link helps http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/

Comment: Unfortunately that example uses as different method of displaying the modal view, as the modal is visible as soon as it's rendered. It's different with a Bootstrap modal.

Comment: I believe the main challenge is that I cannot call a `closeModal` action from a button in my modal view. Bootstrap itself handles hiding the modal, but I need to disconnect the outlet to allow the same or another modal to render.

Comment: Why do u want to let bootstrap handle the close/open of the model for you? Just use a normal button with the `{{action}}` helper, and let ember remove the modal. If u remove the HTML u dont need bootstrap to remove it for you.

Comment: @Krutius Because I want to have that nice fade out. It's all in the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qeqequwimuba/1/edit) It does what you want.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        showModal: function() {

          // This does not work the second time:
          this.render('modal', {
            into: 'application',
            outlet: 'modal'
          });

        },
        closeModal: function() {
            console.log("closing modal");
            return this.disconnectOutlet({
              outlet: 'modal',
              parentView: 'application'
            });
        }   
     }  
});
```

> I believe the main challenge is that I cannot call a closeModal action
>   from a button in my modal view. Bootstrap itself handles hiding the
>   modal, but I need to disconnect the outlet to allow the same or
>   another modal to render.

In order to call this action from your component, you have to send the action from the component to the controller current templates controller:

```
App.BaseModalComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  afterRenderEvent: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$('.modal')
        .on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){

          self.sendAction('action');

        })
        .modal();
  },
});
```

And when you use your component, make sure to assign the action name:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="modal">
    {{#base-modal action='closeModal'}}
      <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
    {{/base-modal}}
  </script>
```

The action will bubble from the controller to the route. This solution allows you to use bootstrap exactly as is, but I find that the solution  [Code Jack](http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) suggested to be much more Ember.

Comment: That works perfectly. I believe I tried with `self.send('closeModal');` and shouldn't this work as well? I see it a bit as pollution to have the action name in the hbs.

Comment: Oh, `triggerAction` is what I am looking for. Brilliant. Thank you so much for your help @sunrize920